# How can I compile a Mustache template into a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I would like to be able to compile a Mustache template like this (*test.mustache*):

```
<b>This is a {{test}}</b>
```

into a function like this:

```
function test(obj) {
    var s = '<b>This is a ' + obj.test + '</b>';
    return s;
};
```

while hopefully leaving all the Mustache functionality intact. Are there any libraries out there that does this or will I have to write my own if I want pre-compiled templates? I plan on using this for a client side application.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you need this?

Comment: As it's been years, I don't precisely recall, but probably for performance reasons. Recently I've been using Jade, which allows me to compile templates to pure Javascript functions.